# move first Tr to thead and replace td to th using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string returned from an ajax call like  this

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ron</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to restructure this to

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Ron</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do this in jQuery?

The line below inserts a thead and copies the first tr into it

```
$(data.d).prepend("<thead></thead>").find("thead").html($(data.d).find("tr:eq(0)"))
```

I am trying to remove the first row in tbody after the previous line by using this line

```
$(data.d).find("tbody tr:eq(0)").remove()
```

How can I append `thead`,move first `tr` in `tbody` to it, replace all `td` inside that to `th` and finally remove the first `tr` from `tbody`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some step by step solution,

```js
var jsonString = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr><tr><td>Ron</td><td>28</td></tr></tbody></table>";
var t =$(jsonString); //jquery Table Object
var firstTR = $('tr:first',t); //geting firstTR
$('<thead></thead>')
  .prependTo(t)
  .append(
    $('td',firstTR).map(
       function(i,e){
         return $("<th>").html(e.textContent).get(0);
       }
    )
);

firstTR.remove();//removing First TR

$("#div").html(t);

//Output
console.log(t.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

My proposal is:

- get the first row and for each cell create the corresponding th cell
- prepend to table body the table header, append the header cells created
- remove the first table body row

```js
$(function () {
  var th = $('table tbody tr:first td').map(function(i, e) {
    return $('<th>').append(e.textContent).get(0);
  });
  $('table tbody').prepend($('<thead>').append(th)).find('tr:first').remove();
  console.log($('table').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ron</td>
        <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make:

```
$('table').prepend('<thead></thead>'); // Add thead
$('table tr:eq(0)').prependTo('table thead'); // move first tr to thead
$('table thead').html(function(id, html) {  // you might use callback to set html in jquery
    return html.replace(/td>/g, 'th>'); // replace td by th
                       // use regExp to replace all
});
```

When you use .prependTo, this move the element to another in top and you might use callback in .html function in jquery.

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/prependto/

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler solution:

```js
t = $('table#tbl2')
firstTr = t.find('tr:first').remove()
firstTr.find('td').contents().unwrap().wrap('<th>')

t.prepend($('<thead></thead>').append(firstTr))
```

```css
table thead tr th {
  background: green;
}
table tbody tr td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1"><tbody><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr><tr><td>Ron</td><td>28</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br /><br />
<table id="tbl2"><tbody><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr><tr><td>Ron</td><td>28</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Here is the explanation of the code:

1. Remove the first `tr` element from the `dom`.
2. Find the `td` elements, take their `contents()` and unwrap the `td`.
3. Wrap each of the `contents()` of the `td` with `th` tag.
4. Add the `<thead>` tag to table and append the `tr` we worked on to the `thead`

Answer (score 1):

Years passed (so no jQuery anymore), and I want to do this and have solved it like this. The idea is 1) get the first row(`<tr>`), 2) replace every `<td>` tags on the first row to `<th>`.

```
const txt = `<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ron</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`;

const el = document.createElement('table');
el.innerHTML = txt;

[...el.querySelector('tr').querySelectorAll('td')].forEach(td => 
  td.outerHTML = td.outerHTML
  .replace(/<td([^>]*)>/, '<th$1>')
  .replace(/<\/td>/, '</th>')
);

console.log(el.outerHTML);
/*
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ron</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
*/
```

Comment: Or you can use ``[...el.querySelectorAll('tr:first-of-type>td')]`` instead of two ``querySelector(All)``s.